# Add a filter row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, user-controls

I implement a filter row in DataGridView using IDataGridViewEditingControl. This is sample code I got from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class UserControlCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public UserControlCell()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value. 
       base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
       UserControlEditingControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as UserControlEditingControl;

    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get { return typeof(UserControlEditingControl); }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get { return typeof(String); }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get { return ""; }
    }
}

class UserControlEditingControl : UserControl1, IDataGridViewEditingControl
 {
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue property. 
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get { return this.textBox1.Text; }            
        set { this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString(); }                       
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method. 
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the  IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method. 
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex property. 
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get { return rowIndex; }
        set { rowIndex = value; }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey method. 
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed. 
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit  method. 
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView property. 
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get { return dataGridView; }
        set { dataGridView = value; }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged property. 
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get { return valueChanged; }
        set { valueChanged = value; }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor property. 
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get { return base.Cursor; }
    }
}
```

In it, UserControl1 is a UserControl that will be host in each cell of fisrt row.

My problem is when I enter any conditions in each filter cell, the conditions that have appeared in all the remaining cells. So how can i fix this?

[image]
[image]

This is my code to assign the filter control to the grid cells:

```
DataGridViewRow rows = new DataGridViewRow();
UserControlCell[] textBoxFilterCell = new UserControlCell[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
     textBoxFilterCell[i] = new UserControlCell();                
     rows.Cells.Add(textBoxFilterCell[i]);
  }
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows);
```

Comment: You're probably initializing only 1 instance of that filter control for all cells. Paste the code where you asign the filter control to the grid cells.